# Displaying the contents of an object

Tags: c#, reflection, localization

```
[Serializable]
public class SampleBase
{
    [HumanReadableAttribute("The Base")]
    public string BaseProp { get; set; } // "testing things"
    public bool AllUrBase { get; set; } // true

    public string AsHumanReadable()
    {
        var type = GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        var stringRepresentation = new List<string>();
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var ca = p.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a => a is HumanReadableAttribute);
            var v = p.GetValue(this, null);
            var t = v.GetType();
            var e = t.IsEnum ? t.GetField(Enum.GetName(t, v)).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HumanReadableAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as HumanReadableAttribute : null;
            stringRepresentation.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", ca ?? p.Name, v is bool ? ((bool) v ? "Yes" : "No") : e ?? v));
        }
        return string.Join("\r\n", stringRepresentation);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SampleClass {
    public enum MyEnum {
        [HumanReadableAttribute("It makes sense")]
        MakesSense,
        [HumanReadableAttribute("It's weird")]
        Nonsense
    }
    [HumanReadableAttribute("What do you think about this")]
    public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; } // Nonsense
}
```

Calling the `AsHumanReadable` method will produce

```
The Base: testing things
AllUrBase: Yes
What do you think about this: It's weird
```

My users may add `SampleClass` objects (or a wide range of other objects implementing `SampleBase`) to a shopping cart which will stored for later use.
A customer care worker will be reading the output for checking up on things.

I've thought about making ToString methods (like `return "The Base" + BaseProp;`) instead. My frist thought is that the attribute approach is the more flexible one.

What are the pros and cons to those two approaches (maintainance, localization (avoid magic strings when possible) etc.)?

Comment: I'm not understanding the purpose here.  Why are you decorating your classes (and forcing consumers of your class to do so), rather than, say, doing some simple logging?

Comment: The purpose is to make it human readable. That and support localization. But the decorating probably is redundant in this case. See my comment to the coon's answer. I don't think logging will solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend dropping the custom implementation and having a look at [`ServiceStack.Text`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), in particular at the [`T.Dump`](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=202) methods.

It's something already implemented and reliable. The only thing that it doesn't cover are friendly boolean strings (Yes/No)/.

A custom implementation involves first creating a good and working solution, which takes time and then maintenance and adding support for new stuff, which also takes time.
There are many ways through which you can do it, with attributes being one of them, but it's simply not worth it when you have `ServiceStack`.

Ultimately, you could modify the T.Dump methods and customize them to fit your requirements. It's still something not from scratch.

Comment: That looks quite promising, that ServiceStack stuff! I've often been needing something like that. It (and Wonko's comment to my question) got me thinking.. If I want to localize the property names, why not just use them as keys, instead of spending time decorating. Or rather, a combination of the class name and the property name for key.